# Ping Clients of Android Mobile AP

Tags: android, connection, client, ping, access-point

I'd like to ping clients of my mobile AP. This way I want to see if the client is really connected to my hotspot, since */proc/net/arp* only refreshes, when I shut down my  hotspot.

This is my AsyncTask:

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        InetAddress ip = (InetAddress) arg0[0];
        this.context = (Context) arg0[1];
        return connected =  ip.isReachable(5000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    android.widget.Toast.makeText(this.context, String.valueOf(this.connected), android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Is there a way to ping a client when your device is not rooted?

Comment: Something to keep in mind: even if sending a ping weren't a problem, there's no guarantee that your clients respond to ICMP...

Comment: But it is better than nothing.;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an IP address, you can do **this**:

```
public static String ping(String _ip) {

    try {
        String command = "ping -c 10 " + _ip;
        Process p = null;
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        int status = p.waitFor();
        InputStream input = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
            buffer.append("\n");
        }
        String bufferStr = buffer.toString();
        return bufferStr;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```